# Random network sleeps when using ubuntu 20.04 server

Tags: networking, pi-4, ubuntu, systemd-networkd

I am trying to setup a cluster of Pi4Bs, and have decided to use Ubuntu 20.04 server 64-bit.

I have setup static IP via Netplan and have disabled cloud-init. (Wired ethernet interface)

But after this i start to experience network "sleeps".

For example:

When a ssh session is left for a few minutes, initial inputs would lag for a few seconds, and then return to normal.

When deploying a simple server that uses TCP, the first query after a few moments of inactivity, would also lag for a few seconds.

Note that this does not happen with DHCP on a fresh install,
I also tried isolating the selected static IPs in my router to no avail.

Why is my network sleeping after a few minutes of inactivity?